# More information on PanAm's first trans-Pacific flight

Tags: airline-operations, aviation-history

I have came across [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/46590/3230), about PanAm's first trans-Pacific flight (SFO-MNL route via HNL, MDY, AWK and GUM). For the text, I'm working on, I was wondering, if there is any source that can provide more information on this route.

Literally:

- years of operation,
- approx. times needed to flight each segment,
- approx. break times (refueling?) times at each mid-point,
- was passengers allowed to leave the airplane during each break?

I'm also interested in getting answer to a question that might be harder to answer (too broad?). How it was possible to service / refuel airplane on airports marked as uninhabited in the original answer (MDY and AWK)?

Comment: [tag:pan-pan] is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many sources of information about these flights that you can find by doing an Internet search. For example, I just used "panam clipper flight sfo to mnl".

The following links should get you started:

In addition to some aircraft information, this link has a schedule image about halfway down the page:
https://www.pacificaviationmuseum.org/pearl-harbor-blog/pan-ams-pacific-clippers/

This link has more Manila-specific info, with a video. 
http://www.lougopal.com/manila/?p=1463

The following link, in the paragraph "Building Bases Across the Pacific" will answer your last question regarding MDY/AWK:
http://www.clipperflyingboats.com/transpacific-airline-service