How do airlines decide whether to renumber a diverted flight, and what are the upsides of doing so?
I read on Singapore Airlines flight to Tokyo diverted to Taipei due to cracked windshield (mirror):

The flight has been renumbered to SQ9876 and will depart Taipei for Tokyo at 8.30pm. It is due to arrive at Haneda Airport at 12.30am on Tuesday, a delay of about 18 hours.

How do airlines decide whether to renumber a diverted flight, and what are the upsides of doing so?

@PeterM Deleting this question here and reposting there wouldn't migrate littleadv's answer. Also your proposed heuristic fails on many questions, e.g. many why questions.

Similar question: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14382/7532
