# Why are aircraft callsigns pronounced over the radio in a non-phonetic alphabet way?

Tags: faa-regulations, radio-communications, phraseology

Why is it numbers are not always pronounced in a phonetic way? For example a flight number of 2390 is pronounced "twenty-three ninety" instead of "two three niner zero"

Comment: I thought you were going to ask, why isn't it pronounced two-*tree*-niner-zero.

Comment: What are you basing this off of @Devron? Are you talking about actual ATC communications or announcements?

Comment: @GdD I know Civil Air Patrol aircraft use exactly the situation the OP is bringing up. They use "CAP 2390" said "cap twenty-tree ninety" instead of "two-tree-niner-zero".

Comment: From actual ATC communications from LiveATC

Comment: Callsigns are only there to distinguish - there's usually no CAP20390 AND CAP2390 (which could both be twenty-tree-ninety) in the same airspace. You'll never hear this when a single wrong digit is important, like headings, frequencies etc

Comment: @sanchises True. The CAP callsign has only 4 numbers in it read in two-number blocks.

Comment: @Devron That is also FAA-land specific. In ICAO-land, it would be *Two Tree Niner Zero* as you correctly pointed out. At least by the book...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [FAA's ATC orders](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf) (section 2-4-20) say that the 'group form' should be used by controllers when talking to any aircraft with an FAA authorized call sign. So you would expect to hear it with airline traffic but not private flights:

> 2. Air carrier and other civil aircraft having FAA authorized call signs. State the call sign followed by the flight number in group
>      form.
>
> **NOTE-** *“Group form” is the pronunciation of a series of numbers
>   as the whole number, or pairs of numbers they represent rather than
>   pronouncing each separate digit. The use of group form may, however,
>   be negated by four-digit identifiers or the placement of zeros in the
>   identifier.*
>
> **EXAMPLE−** *“American Fifty−Two.” “Delta One Hundred.” “Eastern
>   Metro One Ten.” “General Motors Thirty Fifteen.” “United One Zero
>   One.” “Delta Zero One Zero.” “TWA Ten Zero Four.”*

Comment: Followup question, then: what is the reasoning behind this ATC Order? In what way is Group Form beneficial in this instance, while being undesirable for headings, frequencies, altitudes, etc?

Comment: Group form is much shorter to say, taking up less radio traffic.  Also, the exact digits are not important, so long as the aircraft understand "he's talking about ***me***".  With frequencies, headings, altitudes, etc, the exact digits ***are*** important.